# Migrate expression from oracle business intelligence to ssas 2012

Tags: ssas, obiee

I have the following expression in oracle business intelligence

```
lookup( SPARSE TIME_F.TRGT_TIME_PERCENT, 95, SNAPSHOT_F.REPORTING_PERIOD_KEY)
```

How can I do the same in ssas 2012?

Many thanks in advance .

Comment: Would you mind explaining what that expression is doing and where you are trying to use it (in a report, in the model, in a query)? Since I see that it is a lookup, that is usually accomplished by defining relationships in your model in SSAS.  Also, are you using SSAS Tabular or Multidimensional?

Comment: I use this expression in cube ssas mutidimensional .

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by in SSAS? Are you writing a query against it? Are you trying to define relationships in the dimension usage?

Comment: it is a member calculation in ssas cube